# Drop down selection control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a nice little UserControl that is a draggable box with some text in. To the right hand side of the control is a little clickable arrow, which when clicked, I'd like to get a few options pop out of the right of the control.

I have already got a PopoutWindow class, which inherits ToolStripDropDown, which allows me to pop up get a new control to 'pop out' of the right hand side of this arrow with the following usage.

```
  MyPopoutWindow options = new MyPopoutWindow ();
  PopoutWindow popout = new PopoutWindow(options);
  popout.Show(arrowButton, arrowButton.Width, 0);
```

MyPopoutWindow is (currently) a custom UserControl, which I want to be the same as the popped-out body of a ComboBox, or a ToolStripMenu.

Does anyone know of a Winforms control I can use or inherit to get this effect? I've tried using `ToolStripDropDownMenu` and `ToolStripDropDown` but I get the following Exception:

```
Top-level control cannot be added to a control.
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you seen this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/simplepopup.aspx ?

Comment: That's the sort of thing I was after. It's okay now though, thanks, I've got it. I'll add an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually quite obvious (isn't it always!). As I mentioned in the question, I'd tried using a `ToolStripDropDown` but that threw an Exception.

To solve this, I've got `MyPopoutWindow` to inherit `ToolStripDropDown`, but in the constructor, set the `TopLevel` property to false. This worked!

```
public MyPopoutWindow()
{
    TopLevel = false;
}
```